# Raise jQuery-UI confirmation dialog only if certain conditions exist on .aspx form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm having a problem getting my jQuery-UI confirmation dialog to work the way I need it to. I have an .aspx form in Visual Studio with C# code behind. I want to ask the user for confirmation on the submit button, but ONLY if a specific radio button is selected in a RadioButtonList control AND an integer value (a public int property from the code behind) is > 0.

Here's the code for my confirmation dialog:

```
//Confirm Replace Bill Info dialog
var replConfirmed = false;
function ConfirmReplaceDialog(obj, title, dialogText) {
    var rbl = document.getElementsByName("<%= rbReplaceAppend.ClientID %>");
    var infoID = parseInt("<%= infoID %>");
    //Raise this dialog only if "Replace" is selected and there is existing info
    if (rbl[0].checked && infoID > 0) {
        if (!replConfirmed) {
            //add the dialog div to the page
            $('body').append(String.Format("<div id='confirmReplaceDialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>", title, dialogText));
            //create the dialog
            $('#confirmReplaceDialog').dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                close: function(event, ui) { 
                    $('body').find('#confirmReplaceDialog').remove();
                },
                buttons: {
                    'Yes, replace info': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        replConfirmed = true;
                        if (obj) obj.click();
                    },
                    'No, cancel': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return replConfirmed;
    }

    //if "Replace" is not selected (i.e. "Append" is selected), always return true
    return true;
}
```

And here's the section of the .aspx page (it's too long to post the whole thing) where the dialog should be called:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbReplaceAppend" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Replace</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Append</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblReplaceAppend" runat="server" CssClass="instructions" Text="(select 'Replace' to replace the information here with the Bill Request info, or 'Append' to add the Bill Request info to information already present)"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnGetReqInfo" runat="server" Text="Get Request Info" OnClick="btnGetReqInfo_Click" OnClientClick="return ConfirmReplaceDialog(this, 'Please confirm information replacement', 'Warning: you are replacing existing information. Are you sure you wish to do this (cannot be undone)?');" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What's happening is that my dialog is never being raised -- the OnClick event always fires and submits the form.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE** (as requested):
Here are those same sections of code as the browser sees them:

The Javascript:

```
//Confirm Replace Bill Info dialog
var replConfirmed = false;
function ConfirmReplaceDialog(obj, title, dialogText) {
    var rbl = document.getElementsByName('ctl00_mainContent_rblReplaceAppend');
    var infoID = parseInt('10');
    //Raise this dialog only if "Replace" is selected and there is existing info
    if (rbl[0].checked && infoID > 0) {
        alert('conditions exist for confirmation');
        if (!replConfirmed) {
            //add the dialog div to the page
            $('body').append(String.Format("<div id='confirmReplaceDialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>", title, dialogText));

            //create the dialog
            $('#confirmReplaceDialog').dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                close: function(event, ui) { 
                    $('body').find('#confirmReplaceDialog').remove();
                },
                buttons: {
                    'Yes, replace info': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        replConfirmed = true;
                        if (obj) obj.click();
                    },
                    'No, cancel': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return replConfirmed;
    }

    //if "Replace" is not selected (i.e. "Append" is selected), always return true
    return true;
}
```

The .aspx:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="ctl00_mainContent_rblReplaceAppend" border="0" style="font-size:X-Small;">
        <tr>
          <td><input id="ctl00_mainContent_rblReplaceAppend_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rblReplaceAppend" value="Replace" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_rblReplaceAppend_0">Replace</label></td>
          <td><input id="ctl00_mainContent_rblReplaceAppend_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rblReplaceAppend" value="Append" /><label for="ctl00_mainContent_rblReplaceAppend_1">Append</label></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <span id="ctl00_mainContent_lblReplaceAppend" class="instructions">(select 'Replace' to replace the information here with the Bill Request info, or 'Append' to add the Bill Request info to information already present)</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainContent$btnGetReqInfo" value="Get Request Info" onclick="return ConfirmReplaceDialog(this, 'Please confirm information replacement', 'Warning: you are replacing existing information. Are you sure you wish to do this (cannot be undone)?');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$mainContent$btnGetReqInfo&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;valGetRequest&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_mainContent_btnGetReqInfo" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It just occurred to me to open Chrome's Javascript debugger and see if anything is going on there... and there is. I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined` at the line `if (rbl[0].checked && infoID > 0) {`. What that tells me is that Javascript isn't finding my RadioButtonList. Isn't `document.getElementsByName('<%= rblReplaceAppend.ClientID %>')` the correct way to do it?

Comment: What's JQuery Validation? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: It would be good to look at the source that the browser actually sees. You seem to be mixing C# and javascript in a way that I don't think will work.

Comment: @tzerb I just read a little about the jQuery Validation plugin - I fail to see how it would help in this situation. I'm not trying to validate form entries here.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer - for whatever reason, I have to use UniqueID here instead of ClientID (I need to learn what the difference is, and when it's appropriate to use each). After replacing `document.getElementsByName('<%= rblReplaceAppend.ClientID %>')` with `document.getElementsByName('<%= rblReplaceAppend.UniqueID %>')` it works properly.